# Is it possible to detect when a user has re-purchased a non-consumable IAP for free?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

When a user of an iOS app purchases a non-consumable item, then installs that app on a new device, it is possible for them to again go through the standard purchasing logic for that item. The app store will ask them if they wish to spend $0.99 on the item, but if they click "Yes", it will inform that they already own that item, and ask if they wish to download it for free.

I would like to track new purchases in my analytics, and not have them conflated with re-purchased items that a user receives for free. Unfortunately, it seems that this behavior is indistinguishable from a genuinely new purchase, (to the client app).  Apple seems to [say as much](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH8-SW9): "Note: If the user attempts to purchase a product that’s already been purchased, rather than using your app’s restoration interface, the App Store creates a regular transaction instead of a restore transaction. The user isn’t charged again for the product. Treat these transactions the exact same way you treated the original transactions."

In discussing this issue, most posts (and Apple's documentation) say that I should offer a 'Restore Transactions' button to the users. I do offer this button, but it is always possible for users to circumvent this logic, and go through the traditional purchasing route. This is where my tracking will become inaccurate.

Do I have any options? Thanks!

Comment: The daily/weekly and monthly sales reports you get from Apple gives you the real numbers. Far more accurate than any in-app analytics.

Comment: Right, but if you're trying to understand the relationship between purchasing and user behavior, the sales reports aren't useful.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you don't have any options for tracking a new purchase versus downloading a previous purchase for free when a user does an in app purchase.  I have looked into this for the same reason of analytics and I could not find a way to do it.  IAP is set up to make sure that you honor purchases made by the same iTunes account on other devices.

If your users are required to have an account specific to your app to make a purchase you could use that to know if they already have made the purchase or not.  But requiring an account for purchase can lower your conversion rate.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have confirmation of this.